# Trailing return type

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17, trailing-return-type

I see a lot of this kind of code statements in one of well known C++ unit test framework.

This is inline class member function.

```
auto exeName() const -> std::string {
  return m_exeName;
}
```

What benefits does it give? Wouldn't it be the same to write

```
std::string exeName() const {
  return m_exeName;
}
```

I understand what are benefits of trailing return type. But if function returns just string or int or other basic type why we can't just use well known syntax?

Comment: These are technically equivalent. It's a stylistic choice. Trying to explain that is probably out of scope for SO. However, the using trailing return type might be more consistent when you also want to use some deduction techniques.

Comment: @kmdreko I understand what overall benefits trailing return type gives to us. But if function returns just a string or int or other basic type what's the reason to not just use simple and well known syntax?

Comment: @Ashot Khachatryan In this particular case there is no benefit and moreover it is just a bad style of programming.

Comment: I think your question "_if function returns just a string or int or other basic type what's the reason to not just use simple and well known syntax?_" is answered in the suggested duplicate: "_On the other hand, writing `auto main() -> int` looks ridiculous._"

Comment: @AshotKhachatryan some things are opinion based. If you need to use trailing returns at various parts of your code, then using them consistently can improve readability.

Comment: (1) "Why not do it the way we always did it" isn't really an argument not to do something. (2) Some folks will claim that if most of your code already uses trailing return for whatever reason, doing it for consistency is better than the "we always did it this way" argument. And they aren't wrong. (3) As the duplicate says, a trailing return brings no ill properties compared to the traditional syntax, save maybe character count. This bolsters point #2. (4) It's still about style, and so terribly opinion based.

Comment: @AshotKhachatryan As an addition: Many libraries use a format like `clang-format` to get an overall consistent look and tools like `clang-tidy` to be warned about possible runtime problems. Those tools might also be hooked into the CI process rejecting pull requests if those tools report something. And if clang-tidy is e.g. run with [modernize-use-trailing-return-type](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/modernize-use-trailing-return-type.html) it will complain about not having a trailing return.

Answer (score 4):

- It is the only way to do it (explicitly) for lambda:

  ```
  auto l = []() -> int {/*..*/};
  ```
- Benefits comes when using `decltype`:

  ```
  template <typename T>
  auto sum(T a, T b) -> decltype(a + b);
  ```

  versus

  ```
  template <typename T>
  decltype(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<T>()) sum(T a, T b);
  ```
- Similarly, with inner types:

  ```
  auto Container::begin() -> iterator;
  ```

  versus

  ```
  Container::iterator Container::begin();
  ```
- Another benefit is with "complex" return type syntax

  ```
  auto get_func() -> int (*)(char);
  ```

  versus

  ```
  int (*get_func())(char);
  ```

  or

  ```
  auto ::C::foo() -> D;
  ```

  versus

  ```
  D (::C::foo()); // D ::C::foo() would be parsed as D::C::foo();
  ```

Then consistency with above code.

Comment: So, in the OP example above, there is absolutely 0 interest of using a trailing return type.

Comment: @xryl669: Possibly consistency with surrounding code, or guideline. Else indeed just style preference.